# Converting a table to canvas and then downloading the canvas as image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I'm using HTML2Canvas to convert a table to canvas and then I try to download the image using a download button. My code is as below:

```
$("input[alt='save-image']").click(function() {
  html2canvas($("table"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          this.href = canvas.toDataURL();
          this.download = "mypainting.png";
      }
  });
});
```

The table converts to image; however, the image never downloads. Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong or if you would like to know more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download image like this -

```
                html2canvas($('table').get(0)).then( function (canvas) {
                    // document.body.appendChild(canvas);//                        
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
                    //a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
                    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                    a.download = 'mypainting.png';
                    a.click();  
                });
```

Comment: This really helped me a lot. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I made it to work, thanks to  T.Shah, and here is my final code:

```
$("input[alt='save-image']").click(function() {
  html2canvas($("table").get(0), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      a.download = 'Pixel-Drawing.png';
      a.click();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Good one... Don't leave a space in the image name.